Configure magit log to not show author and committer
When using -h "Show header", magit log shows the full commit message as well as author and committer.
Most of the time, I am not interested in author or committer, as I know them anyway, but the information needs three text lines.
Is it possible to configure magit log to get an output like with -h but without author or committer?

magit-log-revision-headers-format is a variable defined in ‘magit-log.el’.

Its value is "%+b%+N
Author:    %aN <%aE>
Committer: %cN <%cE>"

Additional format string used with the ‘++header’ argument.

